# Best way to grab a specific position from a string

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, wmi, wmi-query

I have looked at tons of different takes on this issue with answers varying somewhat depending on how the question was phrased.  It appears that you can either do this using split or using a regular expression.

What I am doing is using WMI to return the BIOSVersion of the motherboard.  For whatever reason, the manufacturer puts a lot more into it than just the version number.  Out of the entire string, the version number is in the third position of the period delimited string.  In the value in the second position is ALWAYS 86A.  In this example, the version is actually `0460.SIX7910J.86A.0460.2012.0327.1627`.

So, which would be the 'best practice' in regards to what I am doing?  A regular expression inside the query expression, looping through the result of using split or something else I haven't found yet?

For reference, here is the C# WMI code I am using.  The example code is using Windows forms because that is what was output by the WMI code creator.  I will be using this in a WPF project, but I don't know that this means too much in regards to the essence of the question.  I think I can work out the code needed, but I'm trying to get a feel with which way is the best way to go.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I apologize in advance if the code doesn't all show up in the code block.  I thought I followed the instructions for how to do that, but in the sample display of the code block it has a little bit of the code in the code block, then goes to normal text and then goes back to code block.  Hopefully the actual rendering is cleaner.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT BIOSVersion FROM Win32_BIOS"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_BIOS instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                    if(queryObj["BIOSVersion"] == null)
                        Console.WriteLine("BIOSVersion: {0}", queryObj["BIOSVersion"]);
                    else
                    {
                        String[] arrBIOSVersion = (String[])(queryObj["BIOSVersion"]);
                        foreach (String arrValue in arrBIOSVersion)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("BIOSVersion: {0}", arrValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use string method IndexOf() to find "86A".  The use Substring to get string.  Always use a simple String method before Regex.  When string methods become complicated use Regex.  Nothing wrong with using both String method and Regex combined if it makes sense.

Comment: Not related to your actual question but there is little point to display `queryObj["BIOSVersion]` after testing if it's null (or did I missed something ?)

Comment: This might go without saying, but the actual "BIOSVersion" is manufacturer dependent.  On my machine, it's a hyphen separated list.

Comment: The only reason *not* to use `.Split('.')` as suggested in some of the answers is if you need some unusually high performance. I know those scenarios exist, but they're not typical - they're rare. And even then I wouldn't think twice about it unless you load test and find that there are performance issues caused by this exact operation. So unless you need to process every motherboard on the continent in several minutes there's almost no chance that it will matter.

Comment: Might not be necessary. This work in PowerShell for you?
`(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios).SmBIOSBIOSVersion`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simplest way if the version is always 3rd from beginning.

```
string s = "SIX7910J.86A.0460.2012.0327.1627";

        string[] arr = s.Split('.');

        Console.WriteLine(arr[2]);
```

hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that replied.  Pretty much all of the replies were great!  It helped clarify things for me quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

First: use @Saket's method, it is clear, easy to read and understandable.
For the sake of completeness, here is one regex approach, nevertheless:

```
(?:[^.]+\.){2}\K # match anything not a dot, followed by a dot
                 # two times and throw it away afterwards
([^.]+)          # match anything not a dot
```

This gives you `0460`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xS5bO4/1).

Comment: Very useful link for regex, Instantly bookmarked. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, when you have the chance to implement string manipulation using String methods only (and the implementation is not complicated) then go for it and don't use regex. This is because most of the methods use low-level C++ implementations while Regex causes more overhead. Your whole code takes around 50ms, so i don't see any need to optimize it more. Just add this to your loop:

```
foreach (String arrValue in arrBIOSVersion)
{
    string[] split = arrValue.Split('.');

    string version;
    if (split.Length > 3)
        version = split[2];
}
```